# how flask sqlalchemy works?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I started learning the Flask framework from YouTube. In the video, it was scripted like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///market.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(length=30), nullable=False, uniq=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    barcode = db.Column(db.String(length=12), nulable=False, uniqe=True)
    discription = db.Column(db.String(length=1024), nullable=False, uniqe=True)

app = Flask(__name__)

    
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home_page():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/market')
def market_page():
    items = [
        {'id': 1, 'name':'Phone', 'barcode': '8932122299897', 'Price':500},
        {'id':2, 'name': 'Laptop', 'barcode': '123985473165', 'Price':900},
        {'id':3, 'name':'Keyboard', 'barcode': '231985128446', 'Price':150}
    ]
    return render_template('market.html', items=items)
```

and in the video, he saves this and runs a cmd and python. Then he runs

```
from market import db
```

then receives a warning and everything is good, but for me, doing this gives a `TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'uniq'`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have several typos: `nulable` should be `nullable`, `uniq` and `uniqe` should be `unique`. These kwargs are not valid if misspelled.

`discription` should be `description`, but that will not prevent your code from functioning, it's just a spelling error.

Comment: OMG thank you for feedback I'm just make them correct